# JWT decode fails with invalid exp value

Tags: jwt, express-jwt

I am using module `jsonwebtoken 8.4.0` in a `nodejs 10.2.0` app. A JWT token is generated on https://jwt.io for test purpose:

[image]

Here in `payload`, the `exp` is expiration date and the string is correctly formatted in JSON. Then the JWT token on the left is submitted to the app for verification. Here is the line of code (as 29:33 below) which fails:

```
const decoded = jwt.verify(jwt_token, process.env.jwtPrivateKey);
```

The error is:

```
{ JsonWebTokenError: invalid exp value
    at C:\d\code\js\emps_bbone\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\verify.js:149:21
    at getSecret (C:\d\code\js\emps_bbone\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\verify.js:90:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as verify] (C:\d\code\js\emps_bbone\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\verify.js:94:10)
    at module.exports (C:\d\code\js\emps_bbone\middleware\auth_userinfo.js:29:33)
```

The error is complaining about the invalid `exp` value. Also obviously there is a valid jwt token generated with the payload. `jsonwebtoken` decode only need to return the original payload `exp`, which is a string, why it failed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide `exp` as *NumericDate*. Apparently you cannot use the date format that you provided.

See documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken#token-expiration-exp-claim

See specification: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.4